# Emptying /var/log/mysql/mysql.log: no permissions

Tags: mysql, linux, permissions

I want to clear the content of `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`. I tried this:

```
sudo cat /dev/null > /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

But it says I don't have permissions. That is strage for me because as you can see I'm running it as root.

Why can I not empty the content of `mysql.log` with that command? What is your advice to empty it?

Comment: maybe the log file is locked/in use by mysql, try killing the mysql process first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `>` operator redirects the standard output from `sudo` (which is invoked with arguments `cat /dev/null`) and therefore you are attempting to write to the log file with your actual user privileges, not with elevated sudo privilege.

You must instead either:

```bsh
sudo bash -c "cat /dev/null > /var/log/mysql/mysql.log"
```

Or:

```bsh
cat /dev/null | sudo tee /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

Comment: That is the right answer. As in a pipe, your sudo privileges vanishes when you do a redirect.